# Selenium WebDriver Firefox

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm running a LAMP configuration on Ubuntu Server 13.04. I setup XVFB and Selenium to load on startup as services (/etc/init.d). Firefox is working if I export DISPLAY before opening it in a terminal session, however I'm not attempting to test in a terminal session; I'm using PHPWebDriver to call an instance of WebDriver.

When attempting to open a session as so:

```
$driver_include = "/includes/user/webdriver/__init__.php";
require $driver_include;
$wd_host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
$web_driver = new PHPWebDriver_WebDriver($wd_host);
$session = $web_driver->session('firefox');
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.
```

I also have Xvfb set to DISPLAY :10. By exporting to this display I can open Firefox in a terminal.

My question is:

***How do I tell WebDriver to use a certain DISPLAY by default without starting it manually from a terminal session?***

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be fine as long as you make sure that the Grid server is running in a shell WITHIN a windowed environment.  It won't work if you start the grid outside of a windowed environment that is needed to start the Firefox profile.   If you are trying to run headless, without a DISPLAY, then you should use GhostDriver/PhantomJS  instead, or something similar.

Comment: Shoulnd't Xvfb be able to handle the display?

Comment: So how does Selenium know which display to use if I have Firefox running in VNC and XVFB?

Comment: It will run in the same display where you started your grid hub.  So, if you are able to get into the display and start the hub then you will also be able to get to the display and see the Firefox browser(s) that it executes.

Comment: I figured it out!! I used the answer from the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040327/selenium-php-unit-and-firefox-on-ubuntu-ec2 and am now running selenium as a service using xvfb-run.